# VM template which automatically joins Rancher environment

Tags: vmware-vsphere, docker, automation

I would like to create a VM template (vSphere specifically) that, when used to create a new instance, will automatically join an existing Rancher environment. I tried running the command from the Rancher Add Custom Host page to create the agent and then freezing that VM as the template. But when I used the template to create a new instance, the agent failed to download the agent from the Rancher server because the server returned an Unauthorized error status. I'm guessing this means that the command from the Add Custom Host page has a timestamp built into it.

Is there another way to setup a VM template that will automatically join a Rancher environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rancher Add Custom Host command is actually only specific to the Rancher Environment, so it can be re-used to add multiple hosts to Rancher. The actual problem I was having was two-fold:

1. If you start Docker in a VM and then snapshot that VM as a template, every new VM created from the template will have the same unique ID for the Docker Engine that is allocated when it first starts up. This can cause various problems. When creating your VM template, ensure that the `/etc/docker/key.json` file does not exist.
2. A similar problem occurs with the Rancher Agent, it cannot be created in the template VM since it also has its own unique ID generated the first time it runs. I solved this by adding a script to the VM template, which is executed when a new VM is created from the template, that starts a new Rancher Agent with the correct registration URL.